# created cloudwatch event from lambda but nothing in Cloudwatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have used the aws api's to create a cloudwatch event from within my lambda. I have logged the successful message back from calling 'putEvents' and this returns:
2017-12-08T15:08:22.582Z    a1d35179-dc29-11e7-ae3c-9354b3005c70    Success

So it was obviously successful but when I try and view the event in Cloudwatch there is nothing there? Where has it gone?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a Rule to read the Custom Event you are pushing to the CW Event. Then you will be able to see the metrics TriggeredRules showing number of successful PutEvent api you are making.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be that you pass on an incorrect timestamp. It's a quick fix, I ran into a bug where we used `int(time.time())` in Python for the timestamp parameter, instead of:

```
int(time.time() * 1000)
```